# Can't enable MySQL 5.6 Query Cache

Tags: mysql, caching

I'm trying to enable MySQL Query Cache on **Ubuntu 15.04** with **MySQL 5.6.25**

I've added this to end end of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`:

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 4096M
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_strip_comments =1
```

The whole server has been restarted more than once.

```
user@myhost:/$ mysql
mysql: unknown variable 'query_cache_type=1'
```

Using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache%'` confirms that `query_cache_type = OFF`

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
/* SQL Error (1651): Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it */
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you do a `find -name "my.cnf"` and see if you have any other my.cnf that may be on your server?

Comment: There are: `./etc/mysql/my.cnf
./etc/alternatives/my.cnf
./var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
./usr/my.cnf`

Comment: what is in the `usr/my.cnf`?

Comment: The only non-commented line is `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

Comment: where did you place your parameters in your `my.cnf`? under [mysqld]?

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` does not contain a [mysqld], so I placed it at the end of the file, but it seems to read from `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` where there is a [mysqld] to which I've appended the lines, and that is all there is in that file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, I've tried it before posting this thread. I don't know of anything else I can do.

Comment: I would suggest posting here http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

edit file /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

add

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1048576
```

Comment: `mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'query_cache_type=1'` I got this error while restarting mysqld